# Adding custom data to order endpoint - no setter?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm trying to add custom data to an order using the REST API.

I have added code which GETS the data from the database, but i'm now looking at how to set this using the REST API.

I have written code, which have relevant getters / setters in OrderExtension, and the name of the field is appearing in the swagger -

[image]

[image]

However, when I try to use this I get this error back -

[image]

Is it possible to update this part of an order once it has been placed? Would I need to create my own endpoint to do this? Or would I need to add it to quote, and then order?

Answer (score 0):

Your `sort_code` field is part of `extension_attributes` for the order, so you need to pass it as such. Note how it's looking for your field on `OrderInterface`, instead of on `OrderExtensionInterface` where it is.

To do that, taking your example, wrap your field in `extension_attributes` like so:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "entity_id": 7,
        "extension_attributes": {
            "sort_code": 321321
        }
    }
}
```

That should map it through correctly.

Comment: I tried this, and the endpoint does accept the data. However, if I then do a GET to the specified order, it doesn't give back the data that was passed to it.

Comment: That suggests your ExtensionAttribute isn't set up fully. You have to have plugins to save data from the extension attr, AND to load data into it. Note for loading that the process can be different for one (getById) versus many (getList). One calls singular load, the other uses a collection. That usually means two distinct load plugins.